# Question on adding a input value to an array using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use setState to update a state array in React using a basic HTML input.
The state I'm trying to update looks like:

```
 "businessName": "",
  "grossAnnualSales": 0,
  "contactEmail": "",
  "numEmployees": 0,
  "annualPayroll": 0,
  "locations": [{"zip": ""}],
  "industryId": "",
```

I need to add a zip code inputted by the user in a React component to this object in the array.

So far I've tried this and it's not working, it just updates to a string and not an array:

```
updateZip(){
return e => this.setState({"locations": [{"zip": e.currentTarget.value}]})
```

}

The React component:

```
<input onChange={this.updateZip()} type="text" className="zip-input"/>
```

How can I update the state succesfully?

Answer (score 1):

use e.target.value and pass onChange={this.updateZip}

```
   class App extends Component {
  state = {
    locations: [{ zip: "" }]
  };
  updateZip = (e) => {
    this.setState({ locations: [{ zip: e.target.value }] });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.updateZip} type="text" className="zip-input" />
        <p>{this.state.locations[0].zip}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-qfgx9)

Comment: That's what I did in my code and it doesn't work, it creates a new undefined key in my state.

Comment: you need to get the e as a parameter

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I edited my answer please check it again

Comment: Gotcha, but it still doesn't work. it creates a new key in state called undefined and adds the user input as a string value to it.

Comment: did you use  e.target.value ?

Comment: did you change onChange={this.updateZip} ?

Comment: Yes and yes, still not working unfortunately.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/add-qfgx9

Comment: I added your code in codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your updateZip function with an arrow function.

```
updateZip = (e) => {
    return e => this.setState({"locations": [{"zip": e.currentTarget.value}]}) }
```

Also

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.updateZip(e)} type="text" className="zip-input"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't update now with the arrow function so doesn't work.

Comment: There is one work around, instead of directly updating zip inside locations, try update locations key.
example:- let loc = [{zip: ""}];
loc[0].zip = <your value>;
location = loc;